# Remove linearly dependent rows/columns of a real symmetric singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, singularity

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a real, symmetric $n \times n$ with its spectral decomposition, $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{X} {\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n)\mathbf{X}^{\rm T}$. Is it true that if $\lambda_i = 0$, then ${\rm rank}(\mathbf{A}_{i,i})={\rm rank}(\mathbf{A})$, where $\mathbf{A}_{i,i}$ is a submatrix of $\mathbf{A}$ obtained by removing the $i$th row/column of $\mathbf{A}$?

I tried to analyze $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_i = \mathbf{0}$, where $\mathbf{x}_i$ is the eigenvector assigned to $\lambda_i=0$. This connection yields

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_{ji} \mathbf{a}_j=0$, (*)

where $\mathbf{a}_j$ is the $j$th column of $\mathbf{A}$. If $x_{ii} \ne 0$ was valid for this $\mathbf{x}_i$ vector, then $\mathbf{a}_i$ could be expressed from (*). However, I do not see anything which implies this assumption.

Comment: The cofactor matrix of $A$ is a matrix of all cofactors, why does it have subscripts $A_{i,i}$?  Also, as is the labeling of these eigenvalues is arbitrary so the question doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.

Comment: @user8675309 You are right with the cofactor matrix: $\mathbf{A}_{i,i}$ is only the submatrix of $\mathbf{A}$ obtained by removing the $i$th row/column pair. My teacher said that one can obtain a nonsingular matrix by removing those rows/columns of $\mathbf{A}$ with indices $i_1,i_2,...,i_m$ for which $\lambda_{i_1}=\lambda_{i_2}=...=\lambda_{i_m}=0$. I would like to understand why this "algorithm" works.

Comment: why not just call it a principal submatrix formed by deleting row/col i?  This doesn't have much to do with cofactors.  The fact that the labeling of eigenvalues is arbitrary is a red flag you didn't understand what was said.

Comment: Yes, I already understood that ordering the eigenvalues is arbitrary. However, the order provided by the Jacobi-method seems to be consistent with leaving rows $i_1,i_2,...,i_m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. We have eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 0$, $\lambda_2 = 1$ and orthonormal eigenvectors $v_1 = (0, 1)$, $v_2 = (1, 0)$. But $A_{1, 1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which has rank $0$ not $1$.

Comment: Thanks for this example, I like it very much! What if we restrict the indices of the eigenvectors $\mathbf{v}_1\mathbf{v}_2,...,\mathbf{v}_n$ such that they should provide a right-hand side coordinate system? In fact, this is the order returned by most diagonalization methods (like Jacobi). Do you have a counterexample in this case, as well?

Comment: @TobiR Yes take $A = \text{diag}(1, 0, 0)$. We have orthonormal eigenvectors $e_2, e_3, e_1$, eigenvalues $0, 0, 1$.

Comment: Witty example, I must admit. For some reasons (most probably due to the shape of Givens rotations), the Jacobi method returns $\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2,\mathbf{e}_3$ for this example, which is alright in view of your example. What if we assume that the modal matrix $\mathbf{X}$ is an infinite product of Givens rotations eliminating off-diagonal elements of $\mathbf{A}$? Sorry for modifying the conditions. I just want to understand whether the order provided by the Jacobi method is consistent with the rank of the cofactors.